# XSL File is not rendering in mobile device browsers

Tags: html, xml, xslt, responsive-design, internet-explorer-11

I am working to make the existing .XSL file responsive. I have completed the code changes and it is rendering properly in IE but while accessing it on any other mobile browsers like iphone, ipad, nokia-lumia etc it's not launching the page at all.

Here is the Abc.xsl file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</xsl:text>
  <html>
     <head>
        <title>XSL Web Page</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="/reporting/css/responsive.css" />
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache" />
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1" />
     </head>
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="//REDIRECT">
           <script language="JavaScript">
              parent.location.replace(" <xsl:value-of select="//REDIRECT" /> ");
           </script>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="//NOACCESS">
                 <body class="container" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000"
                    leftmargin="5" marginwidth="5" padding="5">
                    <xsl:if test="//NOFEECHARGESFOUNDERROR">
                       <br />
                       <br />
                       <br />
                       <br />
                       <div border="0" class="WHITEBG col-sm-12 col-md-10" align="center">
                          <font color="red" size="+2">
                             <xsl:value-of select="//NOFEECHARGESFOUNDERROR/@message" />
                          </font>
                       </div>

  ---------- Contents of the page---------
  ---------- Contents of the page---------

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Am I missing something or is there anything browser specific code I need to include ?

It's working fine in IE only. But in other browsers, it's not landing the page at all.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

For each single page, two xsl files were being added in the controller code (ABC.xsl and ABC3.xsl) itself (in the existing code). which was creating a confusion for chrome and other browsers to render it. But it's shocking, in case of **IE** and **firefox** it was rendering properly.